# htaccess as a security option and using a login form

Tags: security, .htaccess, authentication, recover

I am learning PHP, and I am obsessed with learning security. I know a few about some kind of attacks likes injections, session theft, etc., but I would like to code my own CMS with a perfect security (if possible).

Reading I drop on .htaccess security in directories. This is a good option because all my CMS files are in one directory. I just read this in a website:

> HTAccess is the most secure method of password protection, as it relies on the Web server, so the valid usernames and passwords are never shared with the Web browser or stored in the HTML like they can be with other scripts.

Is this true? I mean, it is "unhackeable"? Of course with extra security (like hidding the .htaccess file).

If this is true, I mean, there is no way to hack a site with .htaccess security, how can I use a form (instead of the popup window) so I can log in my CMS? Is there a way to use a "Forgot Your Password" option?

Any help will be apreciated, as examples and links for reference.

Answer (score 3):

> HTAccess is the most secure method of password protection, as it
>   relies on the Web server, so the valid usernames and passwords are
>   never shared with the Web browser or stored in the HTML like they can
>   be with other scripts.

I'm a little scared of the person who wrote this sentence originally.

Usernames and passwords would *never* be shared with the web browser or stored "in the HTML" except in the cases of the most rank disregard for hygienic programming practices. That someone would even present that as an "option" as a straw man argument is troublesome. I recommend finding a better guide.

The `htaccess` mechanism for server security is also a bit of a misnomer. The `.htaccess` file in directories is really intended to be a mechanism for clients on shared hosting sites to have some degree of control over Apache configuration variables -- which is a complete non-starter for "totally secure CMS system" (as if such a thing were a possibility. :) You should expect to have complete and total control over your Apache configuration, including all [authentication and authorization](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) and [access control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) mechanisms. The `.htaccess` files are re-loaded, re-parsed, and re-configure the server on every single request but the site-wide Apache configuration is loaded once, parsed once, and configures the server once.

The server-based mechanisms rely upon either [HTTP basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (which is roughly akin to shouting your user name and password in a crowded room) or [HTTP digest authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) (which is significantly better and if your users pick good passwords, probably even vaguely safe). Tunneling either one through [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) would be wise. (Heck, if you *really* want "security", you might even go to the effort of using [client certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake).)

Note that these mechanisms ask the browser to pop up a dialog box for authentication. If you want to integrate the username and password into your web page in a "beautiful" way, then you will need to do all the username and password authentication checks via a form submission, storing session information, and checking your internal security mechanisms to provide authorization whenever it is necessary. You will be responsible for everything. (And, again, TLS is the way to go.) The web server cannot help you at all. (And you further won't be sending usernames, passwords to the browser in HTML... sheesh. That still scares me.)

Comment: Thanks for your time in this answer. So, in summary, do you recommend to use htaccess as a security system, or use a php code with some "trics" to avoid injections, etc etc.?? Thanks again.!

Comment: It depends upon what you want for your application: if you want to grant access to the entirety of your application once someone has authenticated, then definitely use the server's HTTP authentication. If you want to provide fine-grained controls based on knowing who the user is (say, allow users to delete their own posts but not someone else's posts), then definitely do the work in PHP with forms for authentication.

Comment: Understood.! Thanks for taking your time to clear my doubts.! :)

Answer (score 2):

is this what your looking for? this will allow you to use a php form to login through htaccess

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
        echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
    }
    ?>
```

[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Comment: And this work with the username and password i set in htaccess.?? Is this secure or there is a way to discover the access credentials with this method.??

Thanks.!
What about changing the htaccess data with php, In this case to use a Forgot My Password option, I mean, generate a new one, so the user can login and the cahnge it again for another he/she sets up.??

My idea is to evaluate what is more secure, using PHP by itself or using HTACCESS.

Comment: To change the password you would have to trigger a server side script. you could look into [this](http://www.cgi101.com/class/password/)

Comment: Basic auth is *not* secure! it send passwords in plaintext equivalent, for every request. (and Digest auth requires the storage of plaintext passwords, so it is not secure either).

Comment: I understand it's just a demonstrative example, but since the OP is really interested in security, I thought i'd point out that this code sample has a cross-site scripting vulnerability.